# Partition column equal to current date in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, partition

I am trying to load data into a Hive table using partition.

The code is as follow:

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE URL(url STRING, clicks INT)
COMMENT 'Unique Clicks per URL'
PARTITIONED BY(dt STRING)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS TEXTFILE
LOCATION '/mypath/URL';

LOAD DATA INPATH '/inputpath/' INTO TABLE URL
PARTITION (dt=date_format(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, "yyyy.MM.dd HH:mm:ss"));
```

I am gettin the following error:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 4:14 cannot recognize input near 
'date_format' '(' 'CURRENT_TIMESTAMP' in constant
```

I tried using

```sql
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

but nothing changed.

Why is it not working?
How to set the current date as partition column?

Thank you in advance.

Lorenzo

Comment: It was very frustrating to answer your question. I strongly suggest you'll read some documentation/tutorials before you continue to work on Hive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Why move the files when you can create the external table on top of them?**
`LOAD DATA INPATH` just moves the files (HDFS metadata operation) "as is", to the table's location.

**Why define the partition column as a string when it is clearly a date?**

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE URL ... PARTITIONED BY(dt DATE) ...
```

**Why are you trying to use non-ISO formats (yyyy.MM.dd)?**
ISO date format is yyyy-MM-dd

---

Since it seems the partition information is not part of the data you have 3 options:

**1.**
Use a constant (no expression are allowed, including functions), e.g.

```
LOAD DATA INPATH '/inputpath/' INTO TABLE URL PARTITION (dt=date '2017-03-04');
```

**2.**
Create an additional table,`URL_STG`, similar to `URL` but without partition and use it to insert the partitions dynamically.

```
set hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

insert into URL select *,current_date from URL_STG;
```

**3.**

Supply the date as a variable from the CLI

```
hive --hivevar dt=$(date +"%Y-%m-%d") -e \
'LOAD DATA INPATH '\''/inputpath/'\'' INTO TABLE URL PARTITION (dt=date '\''${hivevar:dt}'\'')'
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I am sorry it was frustrating, I just started using Hive, however, I am not sure I understood why it was so frustrating. About your questions: 
1) I need to move the data because this is part of a bigger script and the folder containing the data need to be cleared for the next "iteration". 
2) The "string" ended up there after hours of unsuccessful attempts in using dateformats, unixtimestamp and so on, sorry for that. 
3) No particular reason, just unaware copy/past, thanks for the info on the ISO.

Is it possible to define a constant from a function? 
Thanks

Comment: The type of the partition column is string. The name of the partition column is `dt` which suppose to stand for "date". The actual value is a timestamp (up to the seconds level). The format is not ISO. The use of anything but a constant for partition declaration in an error. Dynamic partitions has nothing to do with `load data inpath`. Where do you start to deal with this post? :-) ... and no, you can't use anything but literals